# Capitalization question

Tags: capitalization

Wondering if I could get some advice. Should I capitalize the 'f' in British football? Any advice? Thank you

Comment: How are you using the term?

Answer (score 2):

It is not a proper noun when you refer to the sport in general, so it is not capitalized.

If it forms part of a name, e.g., The English Football League, then it would be capitalized.